# iPhone firmware

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I developed one iPhone application using iPhone OS 2.2. It works fine in the emulator. When I install the application in my iPhone using iTunes (ipa file), it isn't working.

One thing that : my iPhone firmware is 3.0, is it the problem?

Does iPhone OS 3.0 (on real hardware) work the application that are developed on iPhone OS 2.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

no you will need to download the iPhone 3.0 software developers kit (SDK), from the apple iphone developers site. There is a link to download on this page. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/

I believe you also need to sign up to the developers program to actually run your application outside of the simulator. I think the cost to signup for an individual is $100

Comment: I'm pretty sure your answer is wrong twice. 

#1 - it isn't necessary to have a 3.0 sdk to develop software that works on 3.0 iPhones.  2.2 software should run without difficulty
#2 - if he can load the software to his phone, he has already signed up for the apple developer program.

Comment: thanks for replay..

one qstn  is that , in my info.plist i set value of the DTSDKName=iphoneos2.2 is it problem.. pls see the above questions.
pls give my reply dear.

Comment: @kevindtimm - Ok yeah I accept I was wrong about the using a 2.2 program on hardware running 3.0 (but why would you be developing with the 2.2 sdk when everyone is running 3.0 on their hardware?), however noting the users english skills and the way he described the problem I suspected that he may not have got as far as getting the app even onto the phone, thats why I mentioned the developers program.

@Jalju - Please post the exact error message you are getting, rather than just saying it "isn't working". Then we may be able to help more.