# sign up iPhone dev

Tags: iphone

1) can we test our own iPhone application with out Sign up in iPhone Dev Center ?.

2) i am not signed up in iPhone Dev Center ( with paying $99 ), but i developed one
   iPhone  application, it i can't to test my iPhone. is it happened becoz of not signed ?

3) in my application i developed using iPhoneOS 2.2, but in my iPhone Firmware is 3.0 
   is it the reason. ?

4) my application name is "mycalculator" after i compiled i got one "mycalculator.app" file in build folder, in that file one "info.plist" is there. in that plist  i put the value of "DTSDKName = iphoneos2.2" is it that problem...

pls give me actual reason.. may these 4 also the reason ?..

Comment: This is basically the same question as both http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199510/iphone-firmware and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199983/iphone-application-installation, both of which you already have answers for. Why ask the same question again?

Comment: thanks..4 replay and sorry 4 asking same question agin

Answer (score 1):

You must be a paid member of the iPhone Developer Program to test your software on your iPhone. Until that happens, you can only use the simulator.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/

Comment: can we cracked our application.?

Answer (score 0):

In order to test your application on an actual device you must sign up as an iphone developer with Apple.  However you can always use the iphone simulator which comes with the sdk to test your apps for free.